# pgadmin3 failed dependencies which are already installed?

Tags: linux, opensuse, rpm, pgadmin

I try to install pgadmin3 in a system with OpenSUSE 12.1

After download `pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586.rpm` I try `rpm -ivh pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586.rpm` and have the following errors:

```
Failed dependencies:
    libwx_baseu_xml-2.8.so.0(wxcontainer)(WXU_2.8) is needed by pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586
    libwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8.so.0(wxcontainer)(WXU_2.8) is needed by pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586
    libwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8.so.0(wxcontainer)(WXU_2.8.5) is needed by pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586
    libwx_gtk2u_stc-2.8.so.0(wxcontainer)(WXU_2.8) is needed by pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586
    libwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8.so.0(wxcontainer)(WXU_2.8) is needed by pgadmin3-1.14.0-2.1.2.i586
```

I go to `yast` and install every packages relates to `wxContainer`. However, the problem still persists. Seems a path problem?

Download and build wxWidget 2.8.12 give me no luck either :(

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't figure what's wrong with the wxWidget binaries in OpenSUSE 12.1 repository. Or PgAdmin3 1.14. Even after build the source code, pgAdmin hang up at the splash screen

The only work-around I have pgAdmin work is fall back to version 1.12